# Implemented my own version of every() from {purrr}

Tags: beginner, r

I am new to programming / `R` and new to writing `functions`. I am working through the book `R for Data Science` and am on the following exercise:

`Implement your own version of every() using a for loop.`

In case you're unaware, the `every` function from `purrr` does the following:

`Do every element of a list satisfy a predicate?`

Here is the function I came up with:

```
every_2 <- function(x, fun) {
  output <- vector("logical", length(x))
  output2 <- vector("logical", length = 1L)
  for (i in seq_along(x)) {
    output[[i]] <- fun(x[[i]])
    if (sum(output) < length(output)){
      output2 <- FALSE
    } else {
      output2 <- TRUE
    }
  }
  output2
}
```

Using the following numeric vector:

```
test_vec <- 1:100
```

The output matches that of the original `every` function.

```
every(test_vec, function(x) {x > 0}) # TRUE
every(test_vec, function(x) {x > 100}) # FALSE
every(test_vec, is.character) # FALSE
every(test_vec, is.numeric) # TRUE

every_2(test_vec, function (x) {x > 0}) # TRUE
every_2(test_vec, function(x) {x > 100}) # FALSE
every_2(test_vec, is.character) # FALSE
every_2(test_vec, is.numeric) # TRUE
```